# Suppose $G$ is a graph with $n$ vertices and $G$ has no 5-cycle, show that the chromatic number of $G$ is $O(\sqrt{n})$

Tags: probability, graph-theory, coloring

Suppose $G$ is a graph with $n$ vertices and $G$ has no 5-cycle, show that the chromatic number of $G$ is $O(\sqrt{n})$. That is, if $G$ has $n$ vertices and has no 5-cycle, there is some constant $c$ such that the chromatic number of $G$ is at most $c\sqrt{n}$.
I am thinking about using probabilistic method but I have no clue.
Trying to read Noga Alon's "The Probabilistic Method," chapter 10 to find some clue.
[http://math.bme.hu/~gabor/oktatas/SztoM/AlonSpencer.ProbMethod3ed.pdf](http://math.bme.hu/%7Egabor/oktatas/SztoM/AlonSpencer.ProbMethod3ed.pdf)

Comment: what have you tried yourself? Where did this problem come from?

Comment: This is a exercise given by my professor. I have tried to mimic the case when G has no C4, and find an upper bound for the number of edges, but it did not work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is no equally good upper bound on the number of edges in a $C_5$-free graph, because $K_{n/2,n/2}$ is $C_5$-free. You'll have to bound the chromatic number some other way.

Comment: How can I bound the chromatic number if I cannot bound the edge?